# If push notification certificate expired then all existing user stop getting notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have created one certificate for push notification in June 2017 after year it get expired then my app's existing user stop getting notification?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not directly.

It's not so much that your users will stop getting notifications, but rather that you'll lose the ability to send notifications.  The certificate is used for authenticating whatever sending software you're using with Apple's APNS servers.  No valid certificate means no authentication and thus no sending.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes, the users will stop getting notifications.

Apple iOS "Push Certificates" are only valid for a period of 1 year.  A new/replacement certificate for the same AppID must be created and uploaded into AppCenter before the existing Push Certificate expires.

New Push Notification Certificates do not require a new app build unless you have created a new Distribution Certificate.